# JAXB-ElipseLink: Marshaller not validating

Tags: validation, jaxb, schema, eclipselink, moxy

I would like my Eclipselink 2.3 Marshaller to perform validation upon marshalling.
I have made sure that the `Schema` is correctly created by a `SchemaFactory`, i am passing it to `Marshaller.setSchema` and i have registered a handler via `Marshaller.setEventHandler()`.

The marshal result is clearly not valid acc. to its Schema (verified in Eclipse), nevertheless i can see that my breakpoint in `handleEvent(ValidationEvent event)` is never hit.

I am marshalling XML-Fragments using `marshal(Object, XMLStreamWriter)` and would expect the Marshaller to perform validation on these fragments according to the Schema i passed.

Anybody any idea why this is not happening?

**EDIT**:

The Validation error that should occur: 2 missing attributes on an element.

The element corresponds to a Java-Object that is contained in a List<>. I am marshalling the List using:

```
<xml-element java-attribute="listInstance" xml-path="ListWrapperElement/ListElement" type="foo.ElementType" container-type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
```

The mapping for the element itself:

```
<java-type name="foo.ElementType" xml-accessor-type="PROPERTY">
    <java-attributes>
        // just <xml-attribute> elements here
    </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

Therefore all attributes are marshalled to ListWrapperElement/ListElement/@attribute.
2 of these are missing and not detected by validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  Below is what I have tried (adapted from the follow blog post):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

**MarshalDemo (adapted from blog post)**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;

public class MarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("src/blog/jaxb/validation/customer.xsd"));

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        System.out.println(jc.getClass());
        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);
        marshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, xsw);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
2.3.0

EVENT
SEVERITY:  1
MESSAGE:  cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringWithMaxSize5'.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ValidatingMarshalRecord$MarshalSAXParseException: cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringWithMaxSize5'.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  -1
    COLUMN NUMBER:  -1
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  forum8924293.Customer@ef2c60
    NODE:  null
    URL:  null

EVENT
SEVERITY:  1
MESSAGE:  cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ValidatingMarshalRecord$MarshalSAXParseException: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  -1
    COLUMN NUMBER:  -1
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  forum8924293.Customer@ef2c60
    NODE:  null
    URL:  null

EVENT
SEVERITY:  1
MESSAGE:  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element '{phone-number}' is expected at this point.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.ValidatingMarshalRecord$MarshalSAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element '{phone-number}' is expected at this point.
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  -1
    COLUMN NUMBER:  -1
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  forum8924293.Customer@ef2c60
    NODE:  null
    URL:  null
<?xml version="1.0"?><customer><name>Jane Doe</name><phone-number></phone-number><phone-number></phone-number><phone-number></phone-number></customer>
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise, i checked out your blog-post but cant find anything different to what i am doing. Is the Marshaller performing validation after a call to marshal() has finished? In my concrete use-case 2 required attributes are missing from an element and this is not detected by the Marshaller.
Are there any restrictions concerning validation?

Comment: @quaylar - Which part of the XML schema does your object correspond to:  global/anomymous, element/type?  Also is it annotated with XmlRootElememt or wrapped in a JAXBElement?

Comment: Updated my post to give more details!

Comment: @quaylar - Your update did not include the answers to my previous questions.  Would you be able to post a simple example that demonstrates the issue that you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry, its a global named type-definition to which i am referring using the type-attribute of the element. There is no XmlRootElement defined for it!

Comment: @quaylar - I'm still haven't been able to reproduce the issue.  Feel free send me details directly (http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html) if you don't want to post them on the forum.

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts - i decided to validate the file manually since i cannot spend time on this issue anymore for now. I might come back to this later, maybe with a more current version of EclipseLink then.